# Using the Parent constructor to initialize a child class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, openframeworks

I want to create a general class called Button that others inherit from, so that for example I can have StartButton, ContinueButton, etc. There are certain values regardless of the different properties  that I want to start with the constructor since they will always be needed so I built my own Button Class like this:

```
#pragma once
#include "ofMain.h"

class Button {

 public:

  Button(ofPoint _pos, string _text);
  virtual void setup();
  virtual void update();
  virtual void draw();


 protected:
  ofTrueTypeFont buttonName;
  ofPoint pos;
  string text, fontName;
  bool isClicked;
  int buttonFader, buttonFaderVel;

};
```

This is the implementation Button.cpp:

```
#include "Button.h"

Button::Button(float _pos, string _text): pos(_pos), text(_text){

  cout << pos << endl;
  cout << text << endl;
}

void Button::setup(){

 fontSize = 19;
 fontName = "fonts/GothamRnd-Medium.otf";
 buttonName.loadFont(fontName, fontSize);

 cout << text << endl;

}

void Button::update(){

}

void Button::draw(){

 ofSetColor(255);
 buttonName.drawString(text, pos ,pos);
}
```

Now, when I create my first child object I do the following:

```
#include "Button.h"

class StartButton: public Button{

public:

 StartButton(ofPoint _pos, string _text): Button(_pos, _text){};//This is how I use the parent's constructor

};
```

Now in my main.cpp. I thought because I was using the parent's constructor when creating the class I would be able to use the constructor of the parent like this:

```
int main {
  StartButton *startButton;
  ofPoint pos = ofPoint(300,300);
  string text = "Start Button"
  startButton = new StartButton(text, pos); 
}
```

For some reason when I run it and prints the values of the pos and text in the Button class. It prints the string but not the pos. There's definitely an issue passing the information from the child to the parent when the information gets initialized.

Comment: There simply isn't any `StartButton` constructor taking arguments

Comment: so How would I pass values to StartButton?

Comment: If you want to pass parameters through to a base class's constructor you also need to provide those parameters to the derived class. Your derived class's constructor doesn't accept any parameters.

Comment: So basically by having something like this, the parameters will be sent passed all the way to the parent class: StartButton(ofPoint _pos, string _text): Button(pos, text){}; ?

Comment: If the parameter is called `_pos` then you would pass `_pos` that through to the base constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`StartButton` only has one constructor:

```
StartButton(): Button(pos, text){};
```

which attempts to initialize the base `Button` with garbage. You need a proper constructor for `StartButton`:

```
StartButton(ofPoint _pos, string _text) : Button(_pos, _text) {}
```

or if you can afford C++11, inheriting the constructors from `Button`:

```
using Button::Button;
```

Comment: I get the following error: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "typeinfo for Button", referenced from:
      typeinfo for StartButton in StartButton.o
  "vtable for Button", referenced from:
      Button::~Button() in ofApp.o
  NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.

Comment: @mauricioSanchez: Are you defining `Button`'s virtual functions somewhere, or are they supposed to be pure virtual?

Comment: I didn't define it anywhere

Comment: @mauricioSanchez: Well, that's what the linker is complaining about, no definitions for those virtual functions.

Comment: Does this constructor StartButton(ofPoint _pos, string _text) : Button(_pos, _text) {} has to be defined in the StartButton.cpp?

Comment: I think I must be doing something wrong. For the definition of the definition I left it empty but included in the Button.cpp. Now when I create the StartButton and print the values of Button::pos and Button::text it doesn't pass anything, but the app doesn't crash it only doesn't write anything

Comment: @mauricioSanchez: The `StartButton` constructor has to be defined in the `StartButton` class, it's up to you to define it inline or to define it in a source file (any source file).

Comment: I defined it in the header like this: StartButton(ofPoint _pos, string _text) : Button(_pos, _text) {} but when I called StartButton->setup and StartButton->draw and I print the values of string and position it doesn't print anything. I don't know if it is because I'm using the values of the Base class this way: Button::pos and Button::text in the StartButton class

Comment: @mauricioSanchez: That's fine, and it's impossible to know what's going on without seeing your actual code. Maybe you don't really initialize anything in `Button`s constructor.

Comment: Don't know if this is helpful but here is the file https://hackpad.com/Button.h-XhO2IfxyXvp. When I compile it it throws me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address= 0xfffffffc)

Comment: @mauricioSanchez: The "implementation" attempts to access a `startButton` that was never initialized (there's no `new StartButton(...)`.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake. Updated the file https://hackpad.com/Button.h-XhO2IfxyXvp. I had the line but still gives me the error. When the compiler stops it stays at the constructor line in StartButton. I feel that the information is not being passed properly. When I print the values of Button::pos and Button::text in the StartButton class, it doesn't print anything

Comment: @mauricioSanchez: Yes, it seems you are still passing garbage down to `Button`. Look carefully at the code I posted and then at your code, see if you can figure out the problem.

Comment: I tried everything but for some reason when I create the StartButton only the string gets passed not the pos. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I had a typo all the time instead of having this: StartButton(ofPoint _pos, string _text) : Button(_pos, _text) {} I had this: StartButton(ofPoint _pos, string _text) : Button(pos, _text) {} It was trying to pass the value to the actual pos variable inside the parent.