# c++: Can you initialize data in a child class using the parents constructor?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to find out if I can use data initialized by a Parent classes constructor and then use it to populate the child classes vectors. I've been looking for something like this, but the closest I've come to it is here 
[Using the Parent constructor to initialize a child class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25838128/using-the-parent-constructor-to-initialize-a-child-class) , that didn't help unfortunately.

My parent class looks like this

```
class Pile
{
protected:
    vector<int> cards;

public:
  Pile();

  vector<int> getCards();
  void shuffleDeck();
  void dealHand();

  void displayGame();
};
```

Child class:

```
class Hand : public Pile
{
protected:
  deque<int> hand1;
};
```

It's implementation:

```
#include "Declarations.h"
Pile::Pile()
{


  for(int i = 1;i <= 52; i++)
    cards.push_back(i);


  shuffleDeck();

  // What I would like to do.
  // dealHand();

}
```

Ideally, I create a deck of cards, shuffle them, then deal them out where they need to be (the child classes). I know how to do that by instantiating the child classes, creating methods for them, and passing in the vector from the parent class, but that seems awful.

Can you show me a way to move one element from the Pile classes vector 'cards' to it's child class Hand's deque 'hand1' without instantiating Hand? If not, is there a more direct approach than my fallback?

Comment: There is something smelling in this design. Ask yourself: logically, is a `Hand` a `Pile`? Does calling `shuffleDeck()` on an `Hand` instance is meaningful? Inheritance does not seems the kind of relationship to use here (and actually, neither an `has a` relationship seems the right one)

Comment: The `Pile` constructor seems a very bad place to deal a hand unless the `Pile` instance  needs that hand to be dealt. A constructor should do no 
 more than initialize an object and exit. Also think hard on `dealHand` returning `void`. Odds are good that someone will want the hand that's been dealt, and it doesn't look like you've provided any way for them to get it.

Comment: You can do it with hacks by passing pointers to the derived class into a base constructor that accepts a derived pointer. But don't, it breaks a lot of rules because you're supposed to treat each class as its own contained type and you aren't supposed to touch or rely on anything during construction except yourself and parents.

Answer (score 0):

`SomeCards` is a blob of cards.

```
class SomeCards {
  std::vector<int> cards;
public:
  SomeCards( std::vector<int> cards_in = {} ):cards(std::move(cards_in)) {}
  std::vector<int> allCards() const { return cards; }
  void shuffleCards(); // TODO
  SomeCards drawCards(std::size_t count) {
    std::vector<int> r;
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
      if (!cards.empty()) {
        r.push_back(cards.back());
        cards.pop_back();
      }
    }
    return r;
  }
  void addCards( SomeCards in ) {
    cards.insert( cards.end(), in.cards.begin(), in.cards.end() );
  }
};
```

A `Hand` is some cards with extra features.  Also, we want to block dealing hands from hands.

```
class Hand : private SomeCards
{
public:
  using SomeCards::allCards;
  using SomeCards::addCards;

  using SomeCards::SomeCards;
  // TODO more?
};
```

A `Deck` is also some cards with extra features:

```
class Deck : private SomeCards
{
public:
  using SomeCards::SomeCards;
  using SomeCards::shuffleCards;
  Hand drawHand(std::size_t size) {
    return drawCards(size);
  }
  std::vector<Hand> drawHands(std::size_t count, std::size_t size) {
    std::vector<Hand> r;
    r.reserve(count);
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < count; ++i)
      r.push_back( drawHand(size) );
    return r;
  }
  std::size_t drawTo( Hand& hand, std::size_t count ) {
    auto cards = drawCards(count);
    hand.addCards( cards );
    return cards.size();
  }
};
```

Then we build a game from this:

```
class Game {
  Deck deck;
  std::vector<Hand> hands;
public:
  // TODO
};
```

Note `SomeCards` is being inherited from, but privately, because I put common operations on it (that don't identify what the cards are), and I'm using `using SomeCards::operation` to inject them into the private children.

Treating Decks and Hands interchangably is questionable.

We could also strip the non-common functionality out of `SomeCards` and inherit publicly.

This design opens up the possibility that you can write a simple `OrderedHand` that behaves much like a `Hand`, but shuffling it makes sense.

I didn't make much attempt to avoid needless copies above.

Answer (score 0):

The base class constructor runs before the initialization of derived class members. Therefore, it can only modify those members if they have trivial initialization; otherwise it will be undefined behaviour for using a member before its lifetime began.

I would recommend designing your classes differently to avoid such a need.